# iterating over all the subdirectories looking for XML files - Perl

Tags: xml, perl

I am trying to implement a procedure that iterates over all the `subdirectories` from a `root` directory, looking for `.xml` files in `Perl`.

```
sub getXMLFiles {

    my $current_dir = $_[ 0 ];
    opendir my $dir, $current_dir or die "Cannot open directory: $!\n";
    my @files = grep /\.xml$/i, readdir $dir;
    closedir $dir;

    return @files;
}

sub iterateDir {
    my $current_dir = $_[ 0 ];
    finddepth( \&wanted, $current_dir );
    sub wanted{ print getXMLFiles }
}
#########################################################
#                                                       #
# define the main subroutine.                           #
# first, it figures from where it is being ran          #
# then recursively iterates over all the subdirectories #
# looking for .xml files to be reformatted              #
#                                                       #
#########################################################
sub main(){
    #
    # get the current directory in which is the 
    # program running on
    #
    my $current_dir = getcwd;
    iterateDir( $current_dir );
}

#########################################################
#                                                       #
# call the main function of the program                 #
#                                                       #
#########################################################
main();
```

I'm not very familiar with `Perl`. The `sub iterateDir` procedure is supposed to iterate over a the sub-directories, while the `getXMLFiles` would filter for `.xml` files, returning them. I would use those `.xml` files for parsing.  That's why I'm trying to find all the `.xml` files from a `root` directory.
However, I don't know how can I use the `sub wanted` procedure inside `iterateDir` to send the `dirpath` to `getXMLFiles`. How could I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$File::Find::dir` is the current directory name. You can use that variable in the `wanted` sub and pass it to subs you call. See the docs for more info on [the wanted function](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.16.1/lib/File/Find.pm#The_wanted_function)

This should work:

```
sub iterateDir {
    my $current_dir = $_[ 0 ];
    finddepth( \&wanted, $current_dir );
    #                                    |
    # pass current dir to getXMLFiles    V
    sub wanted{ print getXMLFiles($File::Find::dir) }
}
```

Comment: Just one more question, how do I do to print the full path to the file?

Answer (score 0):

Another way...

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Find;
use Cwd;

my $current_dir = getcwd();
my @files;
find(
    {
        wanted => sub { push @files, $_ if -f $_ and /\.xml$/i },
        no_chdir => 1,
    },
    $current_dir
);
```